# ServiceStack Render Razor Fails to Find View

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

This is a self hosted project.  There is a `Views\Member.cshtml` file that is set to copy always as content.  The following when run returns null for the `razorView`.  I seem to be missing something here.

```
    var razorView = razor.GetViewPage("Member"); //e.g. /Views/Member.cshtml
    var html = razor.RenderToHtml(razorView, em);
    Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Furthermore I've tried this and it returns `file not found` although the file is there:

```
var html = razor.RenderToHtml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + 
"Views\\" + "Member.cshtml", em);
```

Also, is there a way to have a service gateway return the rendered razor?

`Member.cshtml` exists: https://db.tt/xuOSAjEj31

`razor`: https://db.tt/qeApkAEZGH

`AppHost.cs`:

```
  Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat() {
        //    ScanRootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Views"
        } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this with the **ServiceStack Self Host with Razor** project in [ServiceStackVS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mythz.ServiceStackVS) after changing each `.cshtml` to **Copy if newer**, changed `AppHost.Configure()` to just:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
}
```

Then added the `HelloView` Service below:

```
[Route("/views/hello/{Name}")]
public class HelloView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, {0}!".Fmt(request.Name) };
    }

    public object Any(HelloView request)
    {
        var razor = HostContext.GetPlugin<RazorFormat>();
        var helloView = razor.GetViewPage("Hello");
        var response = Any(request.ConvertTo<Hello>());
        var html = razor.RenderToHtml(helloView, response);
        return html;
    }
}
```

Which works as expected where `razor.GetViewPage("Hello")` returns the view in `Views\Hello.cshtml` and it returns the generated html.

> Also, is there a way to have a service gateway return the rendered razor?

The Service Gateway is used to call Services which return Typed Response DTOs, not generated html views. You can use `base.Gateway` to access the Service Gateway in Razor Views.

Comment: I am using razor.GetViewPage outside of a service, I'll refactor and see if that's the issue

Comment: I tested your answer in my project and it did not work, `helloView` is always null.  I noticed that the `razor.ScanRootPath` is not set to the Debug folder but not sure if that matters.

Comment: @lucuma don't know anything about your project, but it's working as expected in a new SelfHost + Razor project.

Comment: Project is a test project running hangfire via topshelf and calling a local in proc services via a gateway.  I have no problem uploading it somewhere  and may post it to the forum.

Comment: @lucuma If you're using the latest version of ServiceStack, upload it to a new Github repo and I'll take a look.

Comment: @lucuma Your issue is that you're using an ASP.NET `AppHostBase` base class for a SelfHost project which should inherit `AppSelfHostBase` instead. Also you should have unique names for Views, i.e. there should only be one view page in `/Views` called `Member.cshtml`.

Comment: Thank you, the `AppHostBase` was the issue.